# JFK airport to downtown Manhattan at night

Tags: airport-transfer, new-york-city

I'll be arriving to JFK airport in New York fairly late at night - flight arrival time is 23:10, so with passport control and luggage reclaim, I'm guessing it'll be about midnight by the time I get out of the terminal.

I will need to get to a friend's house in Downtown Manhattan where I'll be staying. Were it in the morning, I'd take the air-train connecting to subway. Uber quotes $85 (don't know whether that includes tolls). I suspect a regular taxi will be even more expensive.

What's the best way (on a balance of cost and time) to get there? I'm willing to spend a bit more to get their quicker/easier.  I will have at most one piece of luggage (a small cabin size suitcase).

Comment: Obvious question: can your friend -- or one of their friends -- drive out and pick you up? (I'm assuming you've already thought of this and the answer is no but I figure it's worth asking just in case a facepalm follows.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well, that would have been the easiest thing, but, no, he won't have a car that weekend.

Comment: There needn't be tolls if your taxi takes the Brooklyn Bridge or the Manhattan Bridge.  Also, what day of the week will you be arriving, and how far downtown is your friend's place?  And why would the air train and subway be acceptable in the morning but not at night?

Comment: Good point on bridges. He lives _all_ the way down - near Battery Park.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to spend a little more to save time, you should probably take a yellow taxi, especially if you're tired.  The fare from JFK to Manhattan is flat; these days it is [about $56 plus tips and tolls](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/tlc/passengers/taxi-fare.page).  If you tell the driver to take the Brooklyn Bridge, which has good access from the Brooklyn-Queens Expressway and to the FDR Drive, there will be no toll.

The air train and subway will be about 80 or 90 minutes (plus up to 20 minutes of waiting for the train) if everything goes well and there are no construction delays (which there often are on weekends and during late nights).  The total fare is $7.75.

The taxi should be 40 to 60 minutes.

Comment: Thanks! Even if there are tolls, the yellow taxi ends up significantly cheaper than uber - I wonder why. $60 is not a deal breaker - sounds like the best solution to me.

Comment: Do the airtrain and subway run all through the night or do the stop after a certain time.

Comment: @Willeke they both run all night.  In the overnight hours, most subway lines run every 20 minutes, but the Howard Beach A train runs with that frequency more or less all the time except rush hours (because half of the A trains do not serve that line and the non-rush-hour service on the main part of the route is mostly every ten minutes).

Comment: @AleksG I don't have much experience with Uber but I do know that their prices vary with demand.  Perhaps you'd get a cheaper quote after you step off the plane.  Taxis are normally very convenient at the airport, though; you just go to the taxi stand and there are a bunch waiting there.  You might have to wait late at night, though; I have had to on one or two occasions, but I don't normally arrive at JFK at that time of day, so I don't know what it's likely to be like there.  Some terminals' taxi stands are farther away, though, which might change the analysis.

Comment: Thanks. I'll play it by the ear when I get there.  It's going to be Friday night, by the way.

Comment: @AleksG I based the estimates on tonight's transit schedule, so they should be fairly relevant.  If you want to reconsider in light of the work schedule for your future trip you may want to check http://www.mta.info/.  They even have a way of looking up service advisories for future dates at http://travel.mtanyct.info/serviceadvisory/, but I suspect that the likelihood of change increases fairly rapidly as you look at dates farther in the future.

Comment: In the end I took a regular taxi.  With tolls and tips came to $60 - cheaper than $70 that Uber wanted :)

Comment: @AleksG thanks for the update.  How long did you wait for a taxi?  How long did the trip take?

Comment: @phoog No wait at all - there were plenty at the terminal. The trip was quite long - probably about an hour if not longer.  Judging the by route he took, I think he was trying to avoid tolls.